# psql: error: server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to postgres I want to containerize postgres , below is my dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:13.3-alpine
ENV POSTGRES_USER="postgres"
COPY . /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
RUN chmod 777 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/main.sh
EXPOSE 5432
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/main.sh"]
```

And i have some Initialization scripts (main.sh) that should run when containers start i have placed them inside  docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files are
.

```
├── ddl
│   ├── create_db_ddl.sql
│   ├── create_index_ddl.sql
│   └── create_table_ddl.sql
├── dml
│   ├── insert_emm_cat4_child_que.sql
│   ├── insert_emm_data_cat1.sql
│   ├── insert_emm_data_cat2.sql
│   ├── insert_emm_data_cat3.sql
│   ├── insert_emm_data_cat4.sql
│   ├── insert_emm_template.sql
│   └── insert_master_data.sql
├── Dockerfile
├── init.sql
├── Jenkinsfile
└── main.sh
```

when i run the container it throws this error message

```
############ Create database and schema if not exist ###########
psql: error: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

this is from my main.sh file
One observation i made if in dockerfile if i dont include `ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/main.sh"]` and after docker exec into postgres container and then run ./main.sh manually it works fine
my main.sh file looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
## SET password
export PGPASSWORD='sapient@123'

#Set the value of variable
database="survey_platform"
user="postgres"
## execute scripts
echo "############ Create database and schema if not exist ###########"
psql -h <IP>-p 5432 -U $user -f "ddl/create_db_ddl.sql"
echo "############ Create table if not exist ###########"
psql -h <IP> -p 5432 -U $user -d $database -f "ddl/create_table_ddl.sql"
echo "############ Create index if not exist ###########"
psql -h <IP> -p 5432 -U $user -d $database -f "ddl/create_index_ddl.sql"
/bin/sh
```

I am confused why i am not able to run main.sh with ENTRYPOINT from dockerfile

Comment: Find the PostgreSQL server's log file and see what it says about why it went away.  Maybe the system log files would help as well, like if it were the OOM killer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `ENTRYPOINT`, or even this wrapper script here.  If you `COPY` the `*.sql` files into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, the [`postgres` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) will run them, in alphabetical order, with appropriate credentials, the first time the container starts up with an uninitialized database.

```sh
FROM postgres:13.3-alpine
COPY ddl/create_db_ddl.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01_create_db_ddl.sql
COPY ddl/create_table_ddl.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/02_create_table_ddl.sql
COPY ddl/create_index_ddl.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/03_create_index_ddl.sql
# No EXPOSE, ENTRYPOINT, CMD, etc.
```

Note that these scripts are only run if the database data doesn't exist at all.  If you store the database data in a named volume or host directory (and you should), these scripts will not be re-run if there's data there.

Fundamentally a Docker container only runs one command, and when that command completes, the container exits as well.  The `postgres` image has [a pretty involved entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/517c64f87e6661366b415df3f2273c76cea428b0/13/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh) that starts up a temporary non-networked database to run the init scripts; if you specify `ENTRYPOINT` in a derived Dockerfile, that command runs *instead of* the standard initialization script or the actual database.  Your setup tries to run `psql` in the container, but since that's running instead of the database, there's nothing for it to connect to.

Comment: I have copied the .sql files to docker-entrypoint-initdb.d but the SQL are not executed , i have to execute  it manually by exec

Comment: as i am getting PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization even after i dont have data directory mounted